# Negative margin Layout to overlay parent layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity that has a toolbar and a framelayout where I inject fragments.

This is the layout for that activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drwDrawerRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_main_selector"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/viewMainToolbar"
                layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frmDrawerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/viewDrawer"
            layout="@layout/view_drawer"
            bind:name="@{name}"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/viewUserDrawer"
            layout="@layout/view_user_drawer"
            bind:name="@{name}"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have the framelayout with a margin so that the contents from the fragments do not overlay the toolbar, but I set clipChildren and clipToPadding to false as per some other posts I have seen here.

On some fragments however I have a loading view, which I would like to occupy all the screen.

This is a sample fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_main"
            style="@style/Layout.FullScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_footer"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                style="@style/Text.Header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_header" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                style="@style/Button.Primary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/support_button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
            style="@style/Layout.FullScreen.Footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footerInfo"
                style="@style/Text.White.Small.Centered"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/footer_info" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/view_loading"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            bind:loading="@{loading}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Ans this is the included loading view, which I have set with negative margin, hoping it would move up to the top of the screen:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLoadingBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="@{loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

    </FrameLayout>
```

Am I missing something here?

Is this doable or do I need to change how I am doing this?

Clarification:
The first / root layout includes a toolbar and the second layout is included within the frame layout of the first. this means that the content of the second layout starts below the toolbar. However, I would like the third layout (a loading screen that is included in the second layout) to have a negative margin so that it overlays the full screen, not just starting below the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CoordinatorLayout` then you wont need negative margins. here are the sample layout u can customise according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_behavior= "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="My App" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <!--include a full screen loading layout here and hide/show according to your need-->
        <include layout="@layout/loading_layout/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain exactly how this works, I am not sure what this will accomplish, or if this would even work with separate and included layouts.

Comment: just replace your fragments in framelayout that is used for fragment container also your question not enough to clear what u need ?

Comment: I replaced the framelayouts and the behaviour is still the same. If my question is not clear I will try to clarify. The first / root layout includes a toolbar and the second layout is included within the frame layout of the first. this means that the content of the second layout starts below the toolbar. However, I would like the third layout (a loading screen that is included in the second layout) to have a negative margin so that it overlays the full screen, not just starting below the toolbar.

Comment: This is exactly why your approach isn't working with me. the loading is within the child, not the parent. How can I achieve this if the loading view is within the child?

Comment: if laoding view in parent you can still call in child by `loadingview=getActivity().findViewById();`